# Can I say like the following?

Tags: reported-speech

In indirect speech, if the reported words are true at the time of reporting, can I say that like the following.

> John asked me if I shall help him.

Comment: What are the reported words?

Comment: John said to me, "Will you help me?"

Comment: John asked me if I would help him. *Would* is the past tense of *will*. If the time for you to help   John is not yet over, you can also say *John asked me if I will help him.*